# Predefining class to avoid "Class undefined" in Visual C++/Cli throws error LNK2020

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++-cli

Well since I was having some undefined class problems, since one header was adding another that was adding itself, it probably was compiling some class that didn't exist at that point, so I made this and put in the beginning, the compilation went normally, but in the very last second of the compilation it threw an error

```
 Error  230 error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600003C) Servicos::.ctor  Servicos.obj
```

-

```
public ref class Servicos: public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
    public:
    Servicos(Usuario*,unordered_map<int, std::string>*);
}
```

Since I wasn't caring at that moment of the other functions, I just put the constructor, because all it does is just instantiate the class to make the Dialog show. (altho I did tried adding all functions too, and same error happened)

This is the original:

```
namespace MyProject {
public ref class Servicos: public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    //... Some Variables declared

    public: 
        Servicos(Usuario* user, 
            unordered_map<int, std::string>* fab_contas_)
        {
            this->fab_contas_email = fab_contas_;
            this->usuario = user;
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

//... And Other Functions
};

}
```

Can any of you guys point where I am doing something wrong? Thank you very much!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does not make much sense to me:  the linker is telling you that the constructor of class `Servicos` was not defined.  The fact that the compilation got to the linking phase means that the ctor was declared (explicitly or implicitly).

public ref class Servicos: public System::Windows::Forms::Form { 
    public: 
    ServicosFacebook(Usuario*,unordered_map*); 
}

It is probably this code that is causing the problem, although it has a syntax error, so this must not be the one you are actually using (otherwise you would not have gotten to the linking phase) -- the function `ServicosFacebook` is not a ctor and does not have a return type.

I assume you have this instead:

```
public ref class Servicos: public System::Windows::Forms::Form { 
  public: 
  Servicos(Usuario*,unordered_map<int, std::string>*); 
}
```

This informs the compiler that there is a constructor (with two parameters) of type `Servicos`, but it is defined elsewhere -- this right here is *the* problem that leads to the linker error, as you do not actually provide a definition.

However the definition for the class where you do define the constructor resides in the `MyProject` namespace, thus is a completely different type.

It is not enough to put the above class declaration into the `MyProject` namespace as that would violate the one-definition-rule: you can have only one definition of a class, but you would have two (even if identical).

To fix, you need to resolve the circular dependency in your header files.  As you do not provide enough information, I cannot help you much there.  If you only need the notion that the class exists, you could use forward declaration in the header to break the circular dependency:

```
class Servicos;
```

This will allow you to declare pointers to that class (as member variables or function parameters).  You will have to include the proper Servicos header in the .cpp file (not in its header)

UPDATE:

Try:

```
// Servicos.h
// include headers that contain the definition of Windows Forms, Usuario,
// unordered_map, string, etc.
using namespace std;
namespace MyProject {  
  public ref class Servicos: public System::Windows::Forms::Form  
  {  

    //... Some Variables declared  

  public:   
    Servicos(Usuario* user,   
        unordered_map<int, std::string>* fab_contas_);

    //... And Other Functions  
  };  

}  

// Servicos.cpp
#include "Servicos.h"
using namespace MyProject;

Servicos::Servicos(Usuario* user,   
        unordered_map<int, std::string>* fab_contas_)  
{  
  this->fab_contas_email = fab_contas_;  
  this->usuario = user;  
  InitializeComponent();  
  //  
  //TODO: Add the constructor code here  
  //  
}  

//... And Other Functions  

// ServicosUser.h
#include "Servicos.h"

// ... declarations that use Servicos

// ServicosUser.cpp
#include "ServicosUser.h"

// ... definitions of things declared in ServicosUser.h
```

Comment: thanks for answering, well I made a mistake there, it was supposed to be "Servicos" and not "ServicosFacebook", I already changed, it's not a redefinition, it's because the class is being declared after the instantiation, so I need to set it up so the compiler knows it exist. I define it in the beginning of my header right after the ifndef statement not in CPP, I don't use CPP, I just  include directly in my header file. I need to define the constructor because I instantiate it to show Dialog before having the class created. how could I do this?

Comment: You need to use .cpp if you want to properly avoid circular header references.  You can define the constructor outside the class definition as: `Servicos::Servicos(Usuario* u, unordered_map<int, std::string>* map) { ... }`

Comment: I did as I showed you before defining the constructor without the content, just like a template, but if I define like you showed you, isn't it going to throw a class already exist error ? would you edit your question and show me how I should do? I've been weeks trying to do this, and I can't  :/ thank you man!

Comment: See updates.  You did not say what causes the circular header references, so I did not put anything in there to fix that.  If this does not work, let me know of the error you are getting and I'll try to help further

Comment: The forward declaration would have to be `ref class Servicos;`